When using numpy advanced indexing with a torch tensor, it sometimes will squeeze dimensions
In this code:
a_numpy = np.array([1,2,3])
a_torch = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
index_torch = torch.tensor([[0]])
index_np = np.array([[0]])
print(f"{a_numpy[index_torch]=}")
print(f"{a_numpy[index_np]=}")
print(f"{a_torch[index_torch]=}")
print(f"{a_torch[index_np]=}")

it prints:
a_numpy[index_torch]=np.int64(1)
a_numpy[index_np]=array([[1]])
a_torch[index_torch]=tensor([[1]])
a_torch[index_np]=tensor([[1]])

notice the odd one out a_numpy[index_torch]=np.int64(1). Why does this happen? Is this a bug?
numpy version: 2.0.2
torch version: 2.5.1

I can confirm that this also happens with Numpy 2.1 (2.1.3 to be more precise, in combination with PyTorch 2.4.0). Looks like a bug to me.

What does np.array(index_torch) (or equivalent torch method) produce? I suspect the error lies in how the  torch instance is converted to something numpy can use.

@hpaulj np.array(index_torch) produces array([[0]]) as expected

Tested with torch 2.0.0 and numpy 1.24.2. The first three examples produce the same result, however a_torch[index_np] returns tensor([1]) rather than tensor([[1]]). I would there is a conversion step for mismatched indexing tensor that has some bugs around unit axes
